# Информер с других ресурсов

Tags: php, html, tpl

Как сделать отображение информации с других сайтов у себя? Пример `http://www.nationalbank.kz/?switch=rus` - справа вверху курсы валют, инфляция и тд.
Нужна только инфа, которая будет обновляться синхронно с ними у меня.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первая [ссылка](http://it-tales.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/PHP/%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%81_%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%85_%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B8_tidy_domdocument_simplexml_%D0%B8_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE_%D0%B6%D0%B5_php.html) из гугла. Дабы не говнокодить здесь - читайте там.
Чтобы синхронно - Вам в помощь cache и cron

Comment: спасибо, помогло